# Can not convert int to string

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
 int CityID= ((User)Session["LoggedInUser"]).CityID;
  //When I debugg I get CityID = 7 here

 ddlCity.Items.FindByValue(CityID).Selected = true;
```

And an error that I can not convert from int to string on the bottom line. How can I make it possibel?

Comment: It's hard to understand from your short description what exactly are you trying to do, and what exactly each of these objects is. Please try to explain your problem better.

Comment: Don't name your variables with capital letters, this is implicitly understood as class name by other programmers, and indeed the coloring algorithm at SO. Note how User and Session are classes and a better name for your CityID would be cityId or cityID

Comment: Even simpler: `ddlCity.SelectedValue = CityID.ToString();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FindByValue expects a string value so you have to convert CityID to a string.

Try this :

```
ddlCity.Items.FindByValue(CityID.ToString()).Selected = true
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been sitting with this for an houre now and it was this simpel. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Parameter type should be `string`, not `int`, so just use built in ToString():

```
ddlCity.Items.FindByValue(CityID.ToString()).Selected = true;
```

---

MSDN: [ListItemCollection.FindByValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbyvalue.aspx) method

```
public ListItem FindByValue(
    string value
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like FindByValue takes "String". Use `CityId.ToString(CutureInfo.InvariantCulture)` instead of `CityId`.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to cast the integer to a string. This can be done in one of two ways

**calling ToString() method**

```
ddlCity.Items.FindByValue(CityID.ToString()).Selected = true;
```

This could raise a null reference exception if CityID is null.

**Using ConvertToString()**

```
ddlCity.Items.FindByValue(Convert.ToString(CityID)).Selected = true;
```

Also it is probably wise to check that the FindByValue method is not returning null as this will also cause a null reference exception when you attempt to set Selected = true

Comment: In which case `(string)CityID` could raise an invalid cast exception?